# How can I connect my Samsung Galaxy S to a television?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, television

My Samsung Galaxy S has settings for TV-out, but I don't see anywhere to plug any cord from the phone to the TV.

How can I connect it to my TV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://www.careace.net/2010/07/28/how-to-use-samsung-galaxy-s-tv-out-feature/), you need a 3.5mm -> RCA/Phono cable, and it goes in the headphone socket of the phone.

Answer (score 7):

See this page for the [Galaxy S's standard TV-Out cable as sold by Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/ECC1TX1BBEGSTA), this plugs into the 3.5mm headphone port on the phone.

It can also output [HDMI via an adaptor that plugs into the micro-USB port](http://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+galaxy+s+hdmi+cable&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=8fD&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbs=shop:1&ei=yaBGTdi0KIewhAe-gdHnAQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=5&ved=0CCsQ_AUoBA&biw=1130&bih=953), though this has the obvious disadvantage that you can't plug it into power to charge at the same time as playing.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) using the AllShare app, if your TV system supports it.