# How to view pictures from Samsung Galaxy Mini on Sony Bravia tv?

Tags: wi-fi, usb, images, television, samsung-galaxy-mini

Any idea how can I connect my Samsung Galaxy Mini to Sony KDL-22EX320 Bravia tv? I cannot get it to show up as a USB device. The tv manual also mentions the possibility of browsing wifi devices but I have no idea how to set up wifi connection between them. Please note I don't want to connect my phone to tv as described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5457/how-can-i-connect-my-samsung-galaxy-s-to-a-television), I just want to get pictures straight off of my phone onto the tv screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "AllShare" apk, which enable you to use DLNA phone device (Im considering that your sony bravia supports DLNA).

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track! Couldn't find AllShare and installed 
iMediaShare   from Android Market. Although the tv does not show up in the app I could browse multimedia on the tv which found DLNA server via wifi without any additional configuration.